# How can I calculate the date picker value and the year, month, and day we set?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a military service calculator website.

I'm posting because I have difficulties with logic in implementing JavaScript.

When you press the first button (class="armyBtn") and the second button (id="datepicker"), you use the datepicker to calculate the year, month, and day values and display the military discharge values in the first row of the table.

In addition, the first button has a different service period value for each county, so the resulting value must be different.

Each military service period is annotated in the JavaScript file.

Each county has a total of seven buttons. And each military has a different service period.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                showOn: "button",
                buttonText: "입대일",
                onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                    var date = $(this).val();
                    var arr = date.split("-");
                    var year = arr[0];
                    var month = arr[1];
                    var day = arr[2];
                    
                    $(".showDate").empty().text(date);
                }
            });
        })
    </script>

// var 육군 = "18개월 = 1 year 6 month"
// var 해군 = "20개월 = 1 year 8 month"
// var 공군 = "22개월 = 1 year 10 month"
// var 해병대 = "18개월 = 1 year 6 month"
// var 사회복무요원 = "21개월 = 1 year 9 month"
// var 의경해경 = "18개월 = 1 year 6 month"
// var 소방원 = "20개월 = 1 year 8 month"
```

Comment: Could you please further describe what you are trying to accomplish with the datepicker? I don't quite understand since you were explaining many aspects of the application in the description

Comment: can u check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68664056/how-can-the-first-button-be-clicked-first-and-output-the-result-value-by-combini

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code

```
-HTML-
<div>
  <input id="datepicker" class="datepicker" value="" readonly />
</div>
<div>
  <label id="result" class="result"></label>
</div>

-JS-
$(document).ready(function () 
{        
     $('#datepicker').datepicker
    ({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        showOn: "button",
        buttonText: "입대일",
        inline: true,
             onSelect: function() {
                var valueSelected = document.getElementById("datepicker").value;
                var dateSelected = new Date(valueSelected);
                var today = new Date();
                var age = today.getTime() - dateSelected.getTime();
                var elapsed = new Date(age);
                var year = elapsed.getYear()-70;
                var month = elapsed.getMonth();
                var day = elapsed.getDay();
                var ageTotal = (year < 1 ? "" : year + " Years,") + month + " Months," + day + " Days";

        $("#result").empty().text(ageTotal);

            }
     });  

});
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/4przok20/